# Remove categories from left side on contact us page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, url, contact-us

i am using 2 column left layout for contact us page i want to hide categories only from left side ! also i want to change URL of contacts to mycustom contact page URL thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1.** How to remove block:

**1.1.** You can remove any block from page by **block name**
Find your block name. And update `contacts.xml` layout for your theme
*app/design/frontend/**[your_package]**/**[your_theme]**/layout/contacts.xml*

Find the following section `<contacts_index_index translate="label">`
and add `<remove name="[your_block_name]" />` where **[your_block_name]** is block name for your categories list.

**1.2.** Or add it to app/design/frontend/**[your_package]**/**[your_theme]**/layout/local.xml

```
<contacts_index_index>
    <remove name="[your_block_name]" />
</contacts_index_index>
```

**2.** How to use custom url:

> 1. In the Catalog menu click on URL Rewrite Management.
> 2. Click the Add URL Rewrite button.
> 3. Choose to add a Custom type.
> 4. Enter "contacts" for ID Path and Target Path.
> 5. Enter "**contact-us**" for the Request Path.
> 6. Click the Save button.

<sup>**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/5897601/664108</sup>

Comment: Hi thanks Neklo (2) Worked but first removing block not working ! can i go through local.xml ?

Comment: Yes, you can. see updated answer point 1.2